# Why Symfony Controller return template snipped with <html> and <body> tags?

Tags: ajax, symfony, twig, symfony4

I have a controller-action:

```
 /**
 * Get the template for the notifications in the user-navbar
 *
 * @Route("/notification/get-template", name="get_notifications_template")
 * @param Request $request
 * @return Response
 */
public function getNotificationsTemplateAction(Request $request)
{
    if (!$request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('homepage'));
    }

    return $this->render('Menu/_notifications_block.html.twig');
}
```

I want to do an AJAX call with to get this template:

```
 refreshNotifications() {

        $.ajax({
            url: this.$wrapper.data('refresh-action-path'),
            method: 'POST',
        }).then(function (data) {

            // remove old notifications
            this.$wrapper.remove();

            // append data to the container
            $('#user-notifications-container').append(data);

            console.log(data);

        }.bind(this))

    }
```

The problem is now - that the Symfony container sends a whole html page:

[image]

the template is that:

```
{% if app.user is not null and is_granted('ROLE_USER') %}
{% if app.user|notifications|length != 0 %}
    {% set notifications = app.user|notifications %}
    {% set all_notification_count = notifications|length %}


        <li class="nav-item mx-2 dropdown js-notification-wrapper data-refresh-action-path="{{ path('get_notifications_template') }}"">
            <a href="#" class="icon-wrapper nav-link btn-lg" data-toggle="dropdown">
                <span class="icon icon-mail" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="badge badge-notification">{{ all_notification_count }}</span>
            </a>

            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right notification-list">
                {% if app.user is not null and is_granted('ROLE_USER') and all_notification_count != 0 %}
                    {% for notification in notifications %}
                        <div class="notification-text">
                            <div class="d-flex">

                                <div class="col-10 px-0">
                                    Kurszugang: {{ notification.courseAction.course }} ({{ notification.courseAction.course.school }})
                                    - {{ notification.courseAction.schoolUser }}
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-2">

                                    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success" id="js-accept-course-action" data-course-action-path="{{ path('course_action_accept_join_request', {'courseAction' : notification.courseAction.id}) }}">
                                        <i class="icon icon-thumbs-up"></i>
                                    </button>

                                    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary" id="js-decline-course-action" data-course-action-path="{{ path('course_action_decline_join_request', {'courseAction' : notification.courseAction.id}) }}">
                                        <i class="icon icon-thumbs-down"></i>
                                    </button>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </li>
                    {% endfor %}

                {% endif %}

            </ul>
        </li>
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

Can somebody tell me - why I can't only the snipped but a whole html page?

I can not append this whole page to the container ...

Comment: just in case, if your ajax request doesn't set the correct header (see: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2ec3e4700103d1a4a4a9a74b413886ed3c0be0cd/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.php#L1685) or if you just access the route in the browser, the request is by default not an xmlHttpRequest, so you'll get redirected to the homepage. So please make certain the request you're sending fits the requirements. Or - alternatively - just remove the whole if-block because I see no good reason to keep it.

Comment: another comment: `$this->redirect($this->generateUrl('routename'))` can be replaced with `$this->redirectToRoute('routename')`.

Comment: Have you provided the entire template? Seems this template is extending a base template.

Answer (score 1):

The way I understand it `render` returns a complete response(with headers), while `renderView` will just return the html.

Try changing this line:

```
return $this->render('Menu/_notifications_block.html.twig');
```

to this:

```
return new JsonResponse([
  'html'=> $this->renderView('Menu/_notifications_block.html.twig')
]);
```

then in the ajax function change:

```
$('#user-notifications-container').append(data);
```

to this:

```
$(data.html).appendTo('#user-notifications-container');
```